# How can i fix the mean of a column of randomly generated values?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to generate a column of random values in excel using:

```
          rand()
```

But in such a way that the mean of those values is always 1. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. `=rand()*2` might be what you're looking for, but it won't "always" be 1.

Comment: What will rand()*2 do exactly? i want the mean of the values in the column to be one cant i put some AVERAGE restriction on it?

Comment: @Dane:i want to implement a queuing system in excel as a discrete event simulation. Need random values for arrival and service rates for this in two columns respectively, but need to restrict the overall value for service rate in the column to one.  A customer arrival and service system is what i want to implement and calculate the mean queue size of customers for different arrival/service ratios.

Comment: So i need to get a set of random values for arrival and service for each run of my simulation (such that overall service rate is fixed at 1 and arrival changes but the ratio of the two remains the same for each run.

Answer (score 3):

In **A1** thru **A20** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

In **B1** enter:

```
=A1-AVERAGE(A:A)+1
```

and copy down thru **B20**

This process is called **scaling** .  Through scaling you can generate a set of values with any mean and any standard deviation.